# Make field in QGIS unvisible

Tags: qgis

I want to use some fields in qgis form but to make it unvisible in table.
Is there any way to do it?

Now if I make the field property unvisible - I can't use it in the form.

I'll be glad to see any hints!

Comment: duplicate the layer, use the first answer below on one of the layer and use the edit/add feature on the otherone. Tricky, but hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes, in this way It will work, but It is not a way out.
I have a lot of such layers and to double them isn't convenient.

Answer (score 1):

At layer properties:

Fields, click in 'Edit Widget', select 'Hidden' option.

[image]

The 'rast_value' field was efectively hidden as it can be observed at the next image:

[image]

However, you can use it at the Python Console of QGIS:

[image]

Result of 'pendingAllAttributesList()' method of **QgsVectorLayer** show that the 'rast_value' field (index 3) is perfectly accessible.

Comment: While this is the obvious answer, do note that the question states that he wants to add a feature by digitizing, which opens the "add feature" form. Hiding the field in the attribute editor also hides it when manually digitizing features.

Comment: I want to use this field in editing form. But if I set it Hidden I couldn't see It in form.